# html code to pop-up image and link to another site

Tags: html, onclick

I have an assignment that I think I am almost complete but my head won't give for much more, maybe I can be assited; my assignment called to create a html form that collects user data and validates user info; which I think I have correctly done. Now I have this instruction which I do not understand but think it is after the validation process "*The merchandize items should include a link to the same or similar items on amazon.com or other retailor sites so that the potential buyers can have a better knowledge of the item and price of the new*;" then I must have a thumbs-up image pop-up after the user clicks on the Submit button but I already have my validation form in the onclick.

Here's my code:

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

 //Function to validate form

 function validateForm() {

     //Variables are declared

     var s=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["itemName"].value;
     var t=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["itemPrice"].value;
     var u=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["location"].value;
     var v=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["itemCondition"].value;
     var w=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["itemDescription"].value;

     //If itemName is entered continue but if left blank show alert
     if (s==null || s=="") {
     alert("Please enter a title for your posting");
     return false;
     }

     //If itemPrice is entered continue but if left blank show alert
     if (t==null || t=="") {
     alert("Please enter the price of your item");
     return false;
     }

     //If location is entered continue but if left blank show alert
     if (u==null || u=="") {
     alert("Please enter your location");
     return false;
     }

     //If itemCondition is entered continue but if left blank show alert
     if (v==null || v=="Select a condition option") {
     alert("Please choose the condition of your item from the list");
     return false;
     }

     //Variables are declared

     var x=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["email"].value;
     var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
     var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
     var y=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["email2"].value;

     //If email address doesn't contain symbol @ or . and a minimum 2 characters
     //after dot then alert to correct email address
     if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
     alert("Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com");
     return false;
     }

     //If second email address does not match first email then alert mis-match
     if (y!=x) {
     alert("Ooops! Your email does not match, please try again.");
     return false;
     }

     //If itemDescription is entered continue but if left blank show alert
     if (w==null || w=="") {
     alert("You must describe your Item for Sale");
     return false;
     }

     }

 </script>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Project Task #1 - AGV</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="document.getElementById('itemName').focus()" bgcolor="E1E1E1">
 <form id="craigslistSalesForm">
 <h2>PA Craigslist - Items for sale</h2>
 <div>
 <span>Posting Title:&#160; </span><input tabindex="1" type="text" name="itemName"
 id="itemName" size="35" maxlength="64" value>
 &#160; &#160; <span>Price:&#160; </span>$<input type="text" name="itemPrice"
 id="itemPrice" size="6" maxlength="9" value>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div>
 <span>Location:&#160; &#160; </span><input type="text" name="location"
 id="location" size="35" maxlength="64" value>
 &#160; &#160; &#160; <span>Item condition:&#160; </span>
                 <select id="itemCondition" value>
                 <option>Select a condition option</option>
                 <option>New</option>
                 <option>Like new (in original packaging)</option>
                 <option>Like new (without original packaging
 </option>
                 <option>Fairly used</option>
                 <option>Used</option>
                 <option>Rough condition</option>
                 <option>Working</option>
                 <option>Not working</option>
                 <option>I don't know</option>
                 </select>
 </div>
 <div>
 &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160;
 &#160;
 <input type="radio" value="Residential" name="typeOfLocation" CHECKED>Residential
 &#160; &#160; <input type="radio" value="Business" name="typeOfLocation">Business
 </div>
 <br>
 <div>
 <span>Your email:&#160; </span><input type="text" name="email" id="email"
 size="35" maxlength="64" value>
 &#160; &#160; <span><i>Retype your email:&#160; </i></span><input type="text"
 name="email2" id="email2" size="35" maxlength="64" value>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div>
 <span><b>Item Description:</b></span>
 <br>
 <textarea cols="80" name="itemDescription" id="itemDescription" style="width: 70%;
 border: 3px solid black; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 24px;" rows="10"></textarea>
 </div>
 <button type="button" value="callTwoFunctions" onclick="validateForm()">
 <b>Submit</b></button>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script you can have additional entry below of all validations you perform, which is accepted as a successful validation result:

```
function validateForm() {

 //Variables are declared

 var s=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["itemName"].value;
 var t=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["itemPrice"].value;
 var u=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["location"].value;
 var v=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["itemCondition"].value;
 var w=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["itemDescription"].value;

 //If itemName is entered continue but if left blank show alert
 if (s==null || s=="") {
 alert("Please enter a title for your posting");
 return false;
 }

 //If itemPrice is entered continue but if left blank show alert
 if (t==null || t=="") {
 alert("Please enter the price of your item");
 return false;
 }

 //If location is entered continue but if left blank show alert
 if (u==null || u=="") {
 alert("Please enter your location");
 return false;
 }

 //If itemCondition is entered continue but if left blank show alert
 if (v==null || v=="Select a condition option") {
 alert("Please choose the condition of your item from the list");
 return false;
 }

 //Variables are declared

 var x=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["email"].value;
 var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
 var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
 var y=document.forms["craigslistSalesForm"]["email2"].value;

 //If email address doesn't contain symbol @ or . and a minimum 2 characters
 //after dot then alert to correct email address
 if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
 alert("Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com");
 return false;
 }

 //If second email address does not match first email then alert mis-match
 if (y!=x) {
 alert("Ooops! Your email does not match, please try again.");
 return false;
 }

 //If itemDescription is entered continue but if left blank show alert
 if (w==null || w=="") {
 alert("You must describe your Item for Sale");
 return false;
 }


 // A place to do additional thing after successful validation
 // you can have another function call
 // i.e. popupImageContainer();

 alert("Yahoo validation is successful lets put another function calls instead this alert code");

 }
```

... also you can have your other function that pops up something by appending its call after `validateForm()` function in your `onclick` event in button tag:

```
`<button type="button" value="callTwoFunctions" onclick="validateForm();popupDialog();">`
```

Comment: My issue is that I have a lot of if statements and what my professor wants now if to do a Validation so that the code still looks clean but that instead of popping an alert every time a cell is left blank to let the user enter all data and after clicking on the Submit button to alert such and such fields were left blank cannot continue until filled or something of the like. Also he wants me to use something like if the Business radio is checked to prevent the user from continuing. Ideas please. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexGonzalez, it is very easy to modify your code to support new scenario. Instead of `alert(...); return false;` you need to populate all failed validations in lets say in an array. and at the end of all validation `if` statements you check whether your array contains any element checking `yourArray.length > 0` and if it satisfies, just loop through that array or use `yourArray.join("some delimiter character here")` method which will create a string concatenation of your elements in that array using the delimiter you specified and alert that as a final result.